# Disable hyperlinks in some entries for glossaries

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I am using the **glossaries** package a lot in my thesis. There are some entries which appear very frequently throughout the whole document. I would like to disable hyperlinking for these entries but keep it for all other entries.

I have tried putting `\glsdisablehyper` just before the frequent entries to no avail.

Comment: `\glsdisablehyper` worked for me, oddly enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For these "frequently appearing" entries use the starred versions of `glossaries`' user commands (e.g. `\gls*`) which suppress hyperlinks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\newglossaryentry{pi}{name={\ensuremath{\pi}},
    description={ratio of circumference of circle to its diameter},sort=pi}

\begin{document}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte} and \gls*{pi}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to disable them (from the command definition?), as I don't want to go through the document and change them all. Thanks for the answer by the way

Answer (score 17):

If you upgrade to the latest version of `glossaries` (v4.09 at time of writing), you can hook into the mechanism that sets the default value of the `hyper` key when using an entry. Here's a simple example that just disables the hyperlink for a specific entry (`ut`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% dummy entries copied from example-glossaries-brief.tex

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{name={lorem},description={ipsum}}

\newglossaryentry{dolor}{name={dolor},description={sit}}

\newglossaryentry{amet}{name={amet},description={consectetuer}}

\newglossaryentry{adipiscing}{name={adipiscing},description={elit}}

\newglossaryentry{ut}{name={ut},description={purus}}

\newglossaryentry{elit}{name={elit},description={vestibulum}}


\renewcommand*{\glslinkcheckfirsthyperhook}{%
 \ifdefstring\glslabel{ut}%
 {\setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}}%
 {}%
}

\begin{document}

Use the entries: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Use the entries again: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Force the hyperlink on: \gls+{ut} or \gls[hyper=true]{ut}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

For a more generalised solution, you could have a list of all the labels of entries that shouldn't have a hyperlink (using, for example, the internal list macros provided by `etoolbox`) or you could use, say, the `user1` key when defining the entry to identify it as one that shouldn't have a hyperlink. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% dummy entries copied from example-glossaries-brief.tex

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{name={lorem},description={ipsum}}

\newglossaryentry{dolor}{name={dolor},description={sit},user1={off}}

\newglossaryentry{amet}{name={amet},description={consectetuer},user1={off}}

\newglossaryentry{adipiscing}{name={adipiscing},description={elit}}

\newglossaryentry{ut}{name={ut},description={purus},user1={off}}

\newglossaryentry{elit}{name={elit},description={vestibulum}}


\renewcommand*{\glslinkcheckfirsthyperhook}{%
 % Get the value of the user1 field
 \glsletentryfield{\thisvalue}{\glslabel}{useri}%
 % Test this value
 \ifdefstring\thisvalue{off}%
 {\setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}}%
 {}%
}

\begin{document}

Use the entries: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Use the entries again: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Force the hyperlink on: \gls+{ut} or \gls+{dolor}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

Another possibility is to allow the hyperlink on first use and then disable it for subsequent use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% dummy entries copied from example-glossaries-brief.tex

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{name={lorem},description={ipsum}}

\newglossaryentry{dolor}{name={dolor},description={sit},user1={off}}

\newglossaryentry{amet}{name={amet},description={consectetuer},user1={off}}

\newglossaryentry{adipiscing}{name={adipiscing},description={elit}}

\newglossaryentry{ut}{name={ut},description={purus},user1={off}}

\newglossaryentry{elit}{name={elit},description={vestibulum}}


\renewcommand*{\glslinkcheckfirsthyperhook}{%
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}
  {%
    % Get the value of the user1 field
    \glsletentryfield{\thisvalue}{\glslabel}{useri}%
    % Test this value
    \ifdefstring\thisvalue{off}%
   {\setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}}%
   {}%
  }%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}

Use the entries: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Use the entries again: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Force the hyperlink on: \gls+{ut} or \gls+{dolor}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

*Edit:* A simpler method is provided with the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package. With this package you can assign a category to each entry. The default value is `general` but can be overridden through the use of the `category` key. This is just a label (avoid special characters) used to identify particular groups of entries independent of the identifiers `type` and `parent`. (For example, `\newabbreviation` sets the category to `abbreviation` and `\newacronym` sets the category to `acronym`.)

Categories can have associated attributes. The `nohyper` attribute indicates that the hyperlink should default to off for those entries. For example, I can have a `common` category (indicating common terms) that has the `nohyper` attribute on:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\glssetcategoryattribute{common}{nohyper}{true}

% dummy entries copied from example-glossaries-brief.tex

\newglossaryentry{lorem}{name={lorem},description={ipsum}}

\newglossaryentry{dolor}{name={dolor},description={sit},category={common}}

\newglossaryentry{amet}{name={amet},description={consectetuer},category={common}}

\newglossaryentry{adipiscing}{name={adipiscing},description={elit}}

\newglossaryentry{ut}{name={ut},description={purus},category={common}}

\newglossaryentry{elit}{name={elit},description={vestibulum}}

\begin{document}

Use the entries: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Use the entries again: \gls{lorem}, \gls{dolor}, \gls{amet},
\gls{adipiscing}, \gls{ut}, \gls{elit}.

Force the hyperlink on: \gls+{ut} or \gls+{dolor}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define during the creation of the acronym/glossaryentry if the page numbers shall be listed in the end by setting the `nonumber` option to `true`. Using `glossaries-extra` this could look like this:

```
\newabbreviation[nonumberlist=true]{foo}{Foo}{Foo description}
\longnewglossaryentry{bar}{name={Bar},nonumberlist=true}{Bar description}
```