# Suppress link in first use of glossary entry

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I'm trying to disable links in the first use of glossary entries. I've seen a number of questions asked regarding the formatting of first uses, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14065/customizing-the-first-use-of-acronyms-generated-by-glossaries) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30167/suppress-the-glossary-expansion-at-first-occurance), and [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48427/suppress-gls-links-on-one-glossary-only) dealing with how to disable links for all items in a *type* of entry. However, none of these seem to do what I want (and that last question, which seems like it would get the closest, has only one answer that hasn't been accepted, for whatever reason).

So far, I've been using `\gls*{<label>}` for first uses. However, since I'm still in my draft phase, I'm not sure what entry will be the first, and I keep finding `\gls*` commands that were first at one point and that I've forgot to update to `\gls`. What I would like is to not have to worry about this, which would be easy if there was some sort of `nolinkonfirst` option, or something of the sort (some of you might say I shouldn't worry about this during the draft phase, but I kinda do, and I thought this might be easily fixed).

I've checked the documentation, and thought maybe redefining `\glsdisplayfirst` or using `\defglsdisplayfirst` would be what I need. However, I cannot seem to understand how to use them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Load the package with

```
\usepackage[hyperfirst=false]{glossaries}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Can't believe I missed it in the documentation.

Comment: Is that also possible for just some glossaries? For acronyms I like `false` but for the main glossary I would like to set `true`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Unfortunately, `hyperfirst` is a package-wide boolean, so it either applies to all glossaries, or none. But maybe @NicolaTalbot can implement it as a glossary-wide option if we ask nicely :-)

Comment: I just did. Thanks for answering. When something is coming up, I hope it will be seen here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127702/32245