# How to set hyperfirst to just one glossary?

Tags: glossaries, subdividing, links

This is a follow up question to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99880/32245).

How can I set my acronyms glossary to `hyperfirst=false` and the main glossary to `hyperfirst=true`?
I tried to give that as an option to `\printglossary` but that doesn't work. In the documentation I can just find a package option to disable hyper references for a particular glossary in total.

Maybe the easiest way would be to set `hyperfirst=true` and just to redefine the first use of an acronym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until Nicola implements this feature in `glossaries` (if ever), I think the only way is to patch the `glossaries.sty` code for all the commands that use the `hyperfirst` feature. As far as I know, they are `\gls`, `\Gls`, `\GLS`, `\glspl`, `\Glspl`, `\GLSpl`. If you know anyone else let me know.

This is my attempt. The code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` does what you want for the default acronym list.

Note that you have to load `glossaries` with the option `acronym` but without the option `hyperfirst=false`.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\def\@gls@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\glsentrytext{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\glsentryfirst{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {\(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
       \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifx\@glo@type\acronymtype%
          \@gls@link[hyper=false,#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
        \else%
          \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
        \fi %
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\@Gls@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \def\glslabel{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\glsentrytext{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}%
          {\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\glsentryfirst{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}%
          {\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
      \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{%
          \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifx\@glo@type\acronymtype%
          \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{%
            \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
        \else%
          \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
            \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
        \fi %
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\@GLS@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
        {\glsentrytext{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
        {\glsentryfirst{#2}}{\glsentrydesc{#2}}{\glsentrysymbol{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}}{%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifx\@glo@type\acronymtype%
          \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
        \else%
          \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
        \fi %
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\@glspl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\glsentryplural{#2}}{\glsentrydescplural{#2}}%
          {\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\glsentryfirstplural{#2}}{\glsentrydescplural{#2}}%
          {\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
         \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifx\@glo@type\acronymtype%
          \@gls@link[hyper=false,#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
        \else%
          \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\@glo@text}%
        \fi %
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\@Glspl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \def\glslabel{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
          {\glsentryplural{#2}}{\glsentrydescplural{#2}}%
          {\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    {%
      \protected@edef\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
          {\glsentryfirstplural{#2}}{\glsentrydescplural{#2}}%
          {\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}}%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
        \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{%
          \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifx\@glo@type\acronymtype%
          \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{%
            \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
        \else%
          \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{%
            \expandafter\makefirstuc\expandafter{\@glo@text}}%
        \fi %
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\def\@GLSpl@#1#2[#3]{%
  \glsdoifexists{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\@glo@type{\glsentrytype{#2}}%
    \def\@gls@link@opts{#1}%
    \def\@gls@link@label{#2}%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @display\endcsname
        {\glsentryplural{#2}}{\glsentrydescplural{#2}}%
        {\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    {%
      \def\@glo@text{%
        \csname gls@\@glo@type @displayfirst\endcsname
        {\glsentryfirstplural{#2}}{\glsentrydescplural{#2}}%
        {\glsentrysymbolplural{#2}}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
    \ifglsused{#2}%
    {%
      \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
    }%
    {%
      \gls@checkisacronymlist\@glo@type
      \ifthenelse
      {%
        \(\boolean{@glsisacronymlist}\AND \boolean{glsacrfootnote}\)
        \OR \NOT\boolean{glshyperfirst}%
      }%
      {%
        \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
      }%
      {%
        \ifx\@glo@type\acronymtype%
          \@gls@link[#1,hyper=false]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
        \else%
          \@gls@link[#1]{#2}{\MakeUppercase{\@glo@text}}%
        \fi %
      }%
    }%
    \ifKV@glslink@local
      \glslocalunset{#2}%
    \else
      \glsunset{#2}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newacronym{acro}{acro}{Test Acronym}

\newglossaryentry{gloss}{name={gloss},description={Test Glossary}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{acro}

\gls{gloss}

\gls{acro}

\gls{gloss}

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This has been logged as [a feature request](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/featuretracker.cgi?action=view&key=14). A new version of `glossaries` is pending (see [pending list](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/#pending)) but as it's a major update it will take a while to complete. In the meantime, here's a possible solution. The assumption is that the main glossary entries have identical first and text keys (which is presumably why you want the first use to be hyperlinked like the subsequent uses, unlike acronyms where the first use gives more detail.):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,hyperfirst=false]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\newglossaryentry{sample2}{name={sample 2},description={another
example}}

\newacronym{ex1}{short 1}{long 1}
\newacronym{ex2}{short 2}{long 2}

\glsunsetall[main]

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{sample}, \gls{sample2}, \gls{ex1}, \gls{ex2}.

Next use: \gls{sample}, \gls{sample2}, \gls{ex1}, \gls{ex2}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of resulting document]

Comment: Thank you. You understood me right. Text and first keys are identical. Thanks for accepting my feature request. But when it is as simple as in your above solution, you could just add this line to your documentation instead of changing something.