# One way links to glossaries

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

Is there any way to have hyperlinks to the glossaries/acronyms (using glossaries package) in only one direction? What I want is a link to the page where an acronym is used, in the list of acronyms. But I would like to disable the links to the page of the list acronyms, which are currently everywhere an acronym is used.

I was not able to find an answer after trying a lot of things. Is there any other way than to add an asterisk at every reference? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: MWE as suggested (reference: [How to combine Acronym and Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}

\begin{document}
\noindent
First use \gls{cd}\\
subsequent \gls{cd}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I want would look like this:

[image]

A similar question is unanswered here: [Disable hyperlinks in some entries for glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25805/disable-hyperlinks-in-some-entries-for-glossaries)

Comment: Use `\gls[hyper=false]{cd}` or `\gls*{cd}`.

Comment: Thanks cgnieder! Is there any other way than to edit every reference with an asterisk?

Comment: There is `\glsdisablehyper`. Just add that to your preabmle after `\usepackage{glossaries}`

Comment: is there a way to to create the hyperlink only for the first occurrence? I know, I can do it manually by using `\gls{}` first, and then only use the starred version. however, I want to avoid scanning my whole document manually and replace everything...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Putting my comments into an answer: the answer can be found in the [user manual of `glossaries`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/glossaries-user.pdf). One can either turn off the hyperlinks of individual occurences by using `\gls[hyper=false]{}` or the shortcut `\gls*{}`. This is described in detail in section 6 “*Links to Glossary Entries*”.

If one wants to disable the links in general one can use the command `\glsdisablehyper`. (There is also `\glsenablehyper` which can be used to turn the links on again. Both commands act locally.) They are explaind in section 6.2 “*Enabling and disabling hyperlinks to glossary entries*”.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}

\begin{document}
\noindent
First use \gls{cd} \\
subsequent \gls{cd} \\
linked {\glsenablehyper\gls{cd}} \\
not linked \gls{cd}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again cgnieder. I did go through the manual but misunderstood this command for disabling links in both ways. Hence never tried it.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this but would any of you happen to know what mechanism is involved in the creation of such clickable boxes ? mine have completly dissapeared, I have no red box on the page number in the glossary nor with the actual word when I use ```\acrshrt{}```