# How use glossaries package with targets (not links) in body of document?

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I want to use the `glossaries` package to create several glossaries—one actual glossary that gives definitions of terms, with page cross-references to where they are defined in the body of the document; and a second list of notation (symbols and their meanings), also with page cross-references to where they are defined in the body of the document.

However, for each entry in one of those glossaries, I do ***not*** want to make the corresponding text/symbols in the body of the document a link to the entry in the glossary. *Just the opposite!* All links are to be in the glossaries, which point back to the text/symbols in the body of the document.

In the docs for glossaries, I only find the `\gls` command, which does just the opposite of what I want.

(I am also using `hyperref`.)

How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Disable hyperlinks in some entries for glossaries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25805/disable-hyperlinks-in-some-entries-for-glossaries) I finally discovered the solution, which is well-buried in `glossaries-user.pdf` (page 54, under option "hyperfirst"):

Use the starred form `\gls*` to suppress putting a link on its argument in the body of the text.

Also, the document `glossaries begin.pdf` indicates explicitly on page 19 a way to disable globally all such links within the body of the text: include in the preamble the command:

```
\glsdisablehyper
```